# How to get only the Whole Number of a Price Value in Decimal from a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid, integer, decimal

I have an SQL Query for price that displays it on a DataGridView with decimals for example (500.00) but the original datatype of the price column is an integer so I had to concatinate in on the SQL Query. The case is when I am getting the value from the DataGridView to a TextBox it gets the whole value with the decimals to the TextBox. What I wish to happen is that it ignores the decimals and only gets the whole number of the price. (500.00 - DataGridView) (500 - TextBox)

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub BilliardItemGrid_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles BilliardItemGrid.CellClick // this is the DataGridView Cell Click function

    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow

        row = Me.BilliardItemGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        Inventory.load_itemtypebilliard(Inventory_EditBothItem.ComboBox1)
        Inventory_EditBothItem.TextBox3.Text = row.Cells("ID").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.TextBox1.Text = row.Cells("Barcode ID").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.Label16.Text = row.Cells("Barcode ID").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.TextBox2.Text = row.Cells("Name").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.ComboBox3.Text = "Billiard"
        Inventory_EditBothItem.Label18.Text = "Billiard"
        Inventory_EditBothItem.ComboBox1.Text = row.Cells("Type").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.Label17.Text = row.Cells("Type").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.TextBox4.Text = row.Cells("Price").Value.ToString // this is how I get the value of the price from the DataGridView to a TextBox
        Inventory_EditBothItem.Label15.Text = row.Cells("Price").Value.ToString // this is how I get the value of the price from the DataGridView to a Label
        Inventory_EditBothItem.TextBox5.Text = row.Cells("Quantity").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.TextBox6.Text = row.Cells("Critical").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.DateTimePicker1.Text = row.Cells("Date Modified").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.ComboBox2.Text = row.Cells("Status").Value.ToString
        Inventory_EditBothItem.TextBox8.Text = row.Cells("Description").Value.ToString

        Inventory.load_givenid()


    End If

    If Inventory_EditBothItem.TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Select a Billiard Item First", "System Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else

        Inventory_EditBothItem.ShowDialog()

        If Inventory_EditBothItem.Visible = False Then
            Inventory.load_billiarditemtable(BilliardItemGrid)
            Inventory.load_bowlingitemtable(BowlingItemGrid)
            Inventory.load_allitemtable(AllItemGrid)
            Store.load_itemstoretable(ItemStoreGrid)
            Reports.load_itemlisttable(ItemTransactionGrid, ItemTransactionComboBoxInDemand)
            Reports.load_audittable(AuditGrid, AuditComboBoxUser, AuditComboBoxType, AuditDateTimePicker1, AuditDateTimePicker2, AuditRadioButtonAll, AuditRadioButtonSpecDate)
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: there is not mysql code  .. in yoru question   .. so way mysql tag ??

Comment: @scaisEdge oh, I’m sorry I’m just used to using those two tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting to an Integer.

```
Inventory_EditBothItem.TextBox4.Text = CInt(row.Cells("Price").Value).ToString
Inventory_EditBothItem.Label15.Text = CInt(row.Cells("Price").Value).ToString
```